# Change MUI Table Cell direction

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

I have a MUI table and I am trying to do something a little bit custom inside a table cell, but the direction is vertical. I want it to be horizontal.

```
 <TableCell align='right' sx={{fontFamily:'Montserrat'}}>
                <button>-</button>
                <p>1</p>
                <button>+</button>
                    </TableCell>
```

[image: how it looks now]

Comment: have you tried just manually setting the flex direction in the style prop? `style={{flexDirection: "row"}}`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this NPM package that i have created recently where you can customize how to render your cells

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fatehmoh/mui-awesome-table